# Dotnet pack ProjectReferences and PackageReferences

Tags: .net, nuget

I'm starting a project Isici over at github. Where I have several projects in the same solution that all publish their own nuget package. There is Isici.Core.Abstractions which is Referenced by Isici.Core and then there is Isici.Configuration.JsonFileConfiguration which references Isici.Core.

Currently there is a 1.1.1 version of Isici.Core available on nuget.org. I updated something in Isici.Configuration.JsonFileConfiguration which makes a package 1.1.6 on nuget.org, but in the dependencies it requires also 1.1.6 for Isici.Core and Isici.Core.Abstractions but I want it to say that it needs to be 1.1.1 or higher (should it exist which it does not...).

below is my csproj for Isici.Configuration.JsonFileConfiguration

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net45;netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <Authors>Filip Stas</Authors>
    <Company>Visuasoft</Company>
    <Product>Isici Feature Flags</Product>
    <PackageLicenseExpression></PackageLicenseExpression>
    <PackageLicenseFile>LICENSE</PackageLicenseFile>
    <PackageProjectUrl>https://github.com/suddenelfilio/Isici</PackageProjectUrl>
    <RepositoryUrl>https://github.com/suddenelfilio/Isici</RepositoryUrl>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Isici.Core.Abstractions" Version="1.1.1" PrivateAssets="none" ExcludeAssets="contentfiles;build" />
    <PackageReference Include="Isici.Core" Version="1.1.1" PrivateAssets="none" ExcludeAssets="contentfiles;build" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="10.0.*" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http" Version="4.3.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Text.RegularExpressions" Version="4.3.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Isici.Core.Abstractions\Isici.Core.Abstractions.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Isici.Core\Isici.Core.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="..\..\LICENSE">
      <Pack>True</Pack>
      <PackagePath></PackagePath>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

**UPDATE:** Settings conditions seems to work, but will make it difficult since versions must be managed manually.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net45;netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <Authors>Filip Stas</Authors>
    <Company>Visuasoft</Company>
    <Product>Isici Feature Flags</Product>
    <PackageLicenseExpression></PackageLicenseExpression>
    <PackageLicenseFile>LICENSE</PackageLicenseFile>
    <PackageProjectUrl>https://github.com/suddenelfilio/Isici</PackageProjectUrl>
    <RepositoryUrl>https://github.com/suddenelfilio/Isici</RepositoryUrl>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="10.0.*" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http" Version="4.3.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Text.RegularExpressions" Version="4.3.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Release'">
    <PackageReference Include="Isici.Core.Abstractions" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Isici.Core" Version="1.1.1"  />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Debug'">
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Isici.Core.Abstractions\Isici.Core.Abstractions.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Isici.Core\Isici.Core.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="..\..\LICENSE">
      <Pack>True</Pack>
      <PackagePath></PackagePath>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use project references then at pack time those are effectively automatically converted to package references, with the minimum version of the references being the version of those projects at the point you built them.

If you want to choose a different minimum version for those dependencies you just need to change them from project references to package references.

Comment: Okay, but during development I want to use the ProjectReferences and not the PackageReferences. How would that work?

Comment: I marked your answer as it pointed me to a solution, thanks @rbennett485

Comment: No problem. Not sure what your solution was, although there's tooling to switch from one to another which is an option https://github.com/RicoSuter/DNT/blob/master/README.md#switch-to-projects